# Grammatical name and function of "whose shoes were damaged"

Tags: phrases, terminology, relative-pronouns

> The boy **whose shoes were damaged** could not go with the others.

What is the grammatical name and function of the bolded part?

Comment: It is a relative clause modifying *The boy*

Comment: Hi, arrian, and welcome to EL&U. Context is always helpful.

It is like saying, *the boy with the damaged shoes could not go with the others.* You have supplied no additional context, so I can only guess that he could not go because of the damaged shoes.

Answer (score 5):

It is a *restrictive relative clause*: it identifies which boy is being referred to.

Answer (score 2):

Relative clause,it qualifies the noun 'boy'

Comment: It does more than this; without commas, it specifies the boy in question. The one with the waggly tail. Sorry, shoes in need of repair.

Answer (score 0):

The word "whose" is a possessive pronoun. It links the subject, i.e. the boy, with his belongings, i.e. the shoes.

Answer (score -1):

It is a relative clause because it introduces the boy in the sentence
 and also qualifies the boy

Comment: It does more than this; without commas, it specifies the boy in question.

Answer (score -4):

WHOSE SHOE WERE DAMAGE  is an adjectival clause 
It tell us more about the subject which is the THE BOY

Comment: "Could not go with the others" tells us more about the boy, too. That alone does not an adjectival clause make. As a side note, please proofread your writing before posting it. (And after posting it.)